# Disabling querystrings and using only paths with /

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using a form and subsequently an action to redirect to another page. Problem is the action redirect function always redirects with a query string and not a full path.
The end url is:
localhost/Get?Description="ddd"&Id=555
Whereas I'd like it to be:
localhost/Get/ddd/222

Here is my code:
My routes:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            "Create", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
            new
            {
              controller = "Home"
            } // Parameter defaults
           );

  routes.MapRoute(
                  "Get", // Route name
                  "{controller}/{action}/{Description}/{id}/", // URL with parameters
                  new
                  {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Get",
                    Description = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional
                  } // Parameter defaults
                 );`
```

The form fills in the description and id and fires the create action, where i'm redirecting to the get action:

```
    public ActionResult Create(string desc,string id)
    {
      System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary route = new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { Description = desc, Id = id });

      return RedirectToAction("Get",route);
    }
```

Finally the get action is fired.

```
    public ActionResult Get(String Description,String Id)
    { return View() }
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to generate a virtual path with RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath. Please reference [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx).